# How can I do pixel-aligned/pixel-perfect/backing store-aligned/crisp drawing on a CGBitmapContext on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm working with vector graphics drawing on Mac OS X (NOT iOS), and I've come across that classic drawing between pixels thing that results in lines being blurry, etc. on Mac OS X when doing vector graphics primitives. I'm doing things directly with Core Graphics/Quartz into a CGBitmapContext.

I found [this blog post](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/are-your-rectangles-blurry-pale-and-have-rounded-corners/) and the Stack Overflow question that spawned it, and I don't want to add 0.5 to each coordinate, because of that article's claim that this breaks on Retina screens.

The article mentions using backing store coordinates, but I can't find any backing store functions in Core Graphics, let alone for just CGBitmapContext.

I have tried both `CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace()` and `CGContextConvertPointToUserSpace()`, both to no avail.

[My bitmap context is transformed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957323/how-do-i-create-a-flipped-cgcontext-on-mac-os-x-that-has-text-drawing-correctly)

What options do I have? Thanks.

**Alternate Question**: is there a way I can just not have point coordinates used, so that (4,4) is always (4,4) and not (3.5,3.5) or something wacky? This is all for in-memory images, so DPI isn't much of an issue yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me, straight from the manual. Hope it helps someone :)

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
r = CGContextConvertRectToDeviceSpace(context, r);
r.origin.x = floor(r.origin.x);
r.origin.y = floor(r.origin.y);
r.size.width = floor(r.size.width);
r.size.height = floor(r.size.height);
r = CGContextConvertRectToUserSpace(context, r);
```